# HTML Link Directly to Content Within Page

Tags: html, hyperlink

I would like to create a link that link directly to content without user trying to find the information by scrolling up & down.

The link is: https://www.scrumalliance.org/why-scrum/scrum-guide

I would like the user to information about "Spirit Planning" immediately after the site is open.

[image]

I know you need an id for the element so you can edit the url & straight away go to content. But for my case, when I inspect element, there are no ID to be found.

The code for "Sprint Planning" are:

```
<h3 class="p5"><span class="s1">Sprint Retrospective</span></h3>
```

Any idea how? Is it even possible to link directly to there?

Comment: AFAIK this isn't possible.

Comment: Are you the owner of that website? If no, then you can't of course.

Answer (score 0):

yes it can be possible.
only if you are admin of both sites. else not at all. if there is no id element.
you have to include id in your html element.

you have to define a div element and give some id to it say "sprint"
 <div id="sprint">

all your code

</div >

and the link that you are linking just add # to it i.e.
say <a href="http://www.com/#sprint">visit sprint </a>

where xyz is the page url it could be anything followed by your id of div where you want the redirection.